# Depth maps (Generated from a LIDAR of an ipad) filtering

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 16-bit, imagefilter

I have 16 bit png files and 32bit exr files of depth maps generated from a LIDAR of an ipad. I need to remove outliers and filter these depth maps without changing depth values of the whole depth map. I tried using opencv filters using kernels but it didn't work as the depth values of the whole depth map gets changed. Then I tried to use opencv-bilateral filter but this function only supports 8u and 32f bit images and it didn't work with my 16bit depth maps. So, I'm wondering whether anyone has a better solution to filter these depth maps using python?

Comment: what kind of outliers you are talking about. If you want to segment some plane or other thing. consider use PCL library instead of opencv.  see https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/statistical_outlier.html

Comment: Post an example image to some free hosting service and put the URL in a comment. Be sure to zip the file so that the service does not change your data or format.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I solved this problem by developing a simple method of identifying outliers using a 11x11 neighbourhood of pixels and removing them while iterating through the whole image. @DrYuanShenghai